# Is it possible to partition a basis $S$ of a Euclidean vector space into a basis for a subspace $U$ and its orthogonal complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a Eucledean vector space with a basis $S=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$. Denote $U$ be a proper subspace of $V$. Can $S$ be partitioned into the union of proper subsets $S_1,S_2$ such that $S_1,S_2$ are bases for $U$ and $U^\perp$ respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple counterexample is $V = \mathbb R^2$, 
$$
S = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}
$$
and
$$
U = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ x \end{bmatrix} \, | \, x\in \mathbb R\right\}.
$$